# Laravel 5.4 Route with Request and Params

Tags: php, laravel

I found myself stuck or lost in docs!

I'm using **Laravel 5.4** and **I'm trying to create validation in a controller** which requires a request object.

My problem is my route passes parameters, I can't find in the docs an example how you include the `Request $request` argument and the `$id` parameter in a Controller method.

Here is my example:

**1: SomeController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
...
public function edit($id) {
    $request = Request; // <-- Do I use that instead of passing an arg?
}
```

**2: Routes with a Paramter in -- routes/web.php**

```
Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], '/some/edit/{id}', 'SomeController@edit');
```

> In their example @ https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#accessing-the-request they have `Request $request` this in their controller, **but what happens to Route parameters?**:

```
public function store(Request $request) {}
```

---

**Question: Do I need to edit the route or is the first parameter ignored if its a request?**

---

**A: Or would I do this in **SomeController.php**?**

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id)
{
    // I would get the $request, but what happens to $id?
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    ]);
}
```

**B: Perhaps, something like this?:**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    // Or Request::getInstance()?
    $this->validate(Request, [
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    ]);
}
```

Any advice would help, or even an example!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Doing

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id)
```

should match the route you already have. So it's ok to do that. `Request $request` here is not a required parameter that you pass. Laravel will take care of it.

It works this way because everytime you send a request, well Laravel 'sends' a request for you (GET, POST). So, it always exist. But you can use use it within your controller if you dont pass it to the controller function as a parameter.

However, you can access it through the global helper function `request()` if you dont want to pass it as a function parameter.

```
$request = request();
$name = $request->name; // or 
$name = request('name');
```

Comment: I would add that using dependency injection (where the `$request` is passed as a type hinted argument is good (better) practice.

Comment: Great advice @Rob